# Getting 500 Server Error after deploying application on google app engine from command line

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am deploying an application to google app engine command line. When I try to access my application after the successful deployment of my App on GAE (The admin logs shows that a new version is deployed successfully.) I am able to successfully access the servlet when I deploy the app using appengine plugin from Eclipse Juno. I am on Mac OSX
I am able to access the index.html successfully though. My appengine-web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>my-app-id</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: I get following exception. 

Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/OutOfScopeException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException

Comment: I am using appengine-java-sdk 1.7.5

Comment: What commands do you use, and is there anything particular about it or the location of your jar lib folder or build path in eclipse?  From the exception it would seem you use Guice and those jar files are not deployed.  Index.html may work if it's a static file.

Comment: I verified it has guice related jars in the lib folder. I am using Maven to build a war

Comment: Found the fix here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711267/google-app-engine-classnotfoundexception-after-deploy-but-runs-fine-on-local-se?rq=1